# how to reduce the time for execution of Docker service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

- I am deploying my node service on Docker.

  - The docker takes more than 10 minutes to build a service and run it on ubuntu machine

Below is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node

ARG ENVIRONMENT
ARG PORT

ENV PORT $PORT
ENV ENVIRONMENT $ENVIRONMENT

RUN apt-get update -qq
RUN apt-get install --yes curl
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -my wget gnupg
RUN curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install --yes nodejs
RUN apt-get install --yes build-essential vim

RUN mkdir /auth_service
ADD . /auth_service
WORKDIR /auth_service

RUN npm install -g express
RUN npm install -g path
RUN npm cache verify
RUN npm install

EXPOSE $PORT

ENTRYPOINT [ "node",  "server.js" ]
CMD [ $PORT, $ENVIRONMENT ]
```

And I am running the service using code

```
#!/bin/bash
ORGANISATION="$1"
SERVICE_NAME="$2"
VERSION="$3"
ENVIRONMENT="$4"
INTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER="$5"
EXTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER="$6"
NETWORK="$7"
sudo docker build -t ${ORGANISATION}/${SERVICE_NAME}:${VERSION} --build-arg PORT=${INTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER} --build-arg ENVIRONMENT=${ENVIRONMENT} --no-cache .
sudo docker stop ${SERVICE_NAME}
sudo docker rm ${SERVICE_NAME}

docker run -p ${EXTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER}:${INTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER} --network ${NETWORK} --name ${SERVICE_NAME} --restart always -m 1024M --memory-swap -1 -itd ${ORGANISATION}/${SERVICE_NAME}:${VERSION}
```

Also, I get below error in the build and deploy process.

**`debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed`**

Please suggest changes to improve the time of execution

Thanks in advance

Comment: Build time of the image should be irrelevant because you should be doing it only once. After that you just create new container based on image with `docker` or `docker-compose`.

Comment: I am using only Dockerfile and running it using docker run command

Comment: Build it with `docker build -t yourimgname .` and then run it with `docker run -ti yourimgname`. This should reuse the image.

Comment: I am doing the same Please see my dockerRun code

Comment: If you use that script to start your service it keeps rebuilding your image unnecessarily. Build it once and use `docker run` to exec it. You can add `--rm` flag to `docker run` to clean up container after it finishes.

Comment: Okay, My intention is to configure it for CI-CD approach. Every time the new code checked in it should delete the old image and build a new one.

Comment: If you insist on building and running as a single step, you'd have to leverage image cache. I see you are using `--no-cache` option in `docker build` and you depend on ENV vars alot in your `Dockerfile` that is probably not helping to use cache. You could for example `EXPORT` static port and use port mapping in `docker run` instead. That would be my generali advice.

Comment: Your Dockerfile has seperate statement which in turns increase build time , as each instruction it is going to create a container and then drop it when that instruction is over. it's better to join different RUN statement (using && \ ) as much as possible to give one complete RUN statement.

Comment: I'm not sure why you install `node` again since it's a `node` image already. But this shouldn't affect your build time if you turn cache on by removing `--no-cache`

Answer (score 0):

There are some improvements that I can think of.

### Remove `--no-cache`

As other comments suggested, this will dramatically reduce your build time. Other suggestions below also need you to remove `--no-cache` first.

### Reorder your commands

Reorder some of the commands to be before ADD/COPY

```
RUN npm install -g express
RUN npm install -g path
RUN npm cache verify
```

Since ADD/COPY check for your file changes, you are likely to install `express` and `path` every times you build the image without using any cache.

### COPY `package.json` first

You may consider `COPY package.json` alone and `RUN npm install` first. Then, `COPY` other files to the context. This will ensure your dependencies and cache them, so next time if there is no changes to your dependency list, you won't need to spend time installing them again.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues here but to summarise in a single answer:

1. Don't build every time. Build once, run multiple times.
2. You are passing in build args (PORT, ENVIRONMENT) which should be runtime args. Pass these in as environment variables on your docker run command and soft code them in the entryPoint (otherwise you'll have to build every time and will never be able to re-use the image for a different PORT/ENVIRONMENT)
3. Don't use the no-cache option on the build
4. Don't have RUN statements running a single OS command, aggregate them e.g. `RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install --yes curl`  etc.
5. Re-order the commands so that the ones least likely to change appear first in the docker file, this means existing layers are more likely to be re-used when rebuilding